# OSB Service based on WSDL having multiple ports

Tags: web-services, osb

How are you doing!
I have a scenario where I need to create an OSB service(which is a mere pass-through service) that will be based on a WSDL that contains 2 ports, each pointing to a different URL. In this case, How do I create the proxy and business services. As I see, when I create the proxy service based on a Port, only one port can be selected at a time, so I'll need 2 OSB Services/proxies. If I select the binding, then the port informaiton won't come from the wsdl into the generated effective proxy wsdl, and it will have only one port, so even in this case, I'll have to generate 2 wsdl's for those 2 ports. Am I right? or Am I missing anything?

Another question on the same scenario
We are storing all the wsdl's in MDS, so need they are abstract(atleast not service/port information). So, in this case, if I make the wsdl as abstract, it will lose the port information, so how do I do? 2 business services, each pointing to a different URL? So even in this case, what about the proxy service? How can a proxy service that exposes one port cater to 2 different services?

Is there anyway that I can achieve this with a single OSB Service? I would prefer the 2nd approach of storing abstract wsdl's in MDS.

Regards
RaviKiran

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Proxy service, you have full control over how that proxy service calls out to business services.  In your case, something simple like an Operational Branch would suffice, but really, OSB allows you to control calling out to multiple services.  You don't need to provide multiple ports for your proxy service, as you can make all the calls and control from inside.

Regarding your second question, it wouldn't matter if you're using abstract or concrete WSDLs in your OSB configuration for either the Proxy or the Business Services.  **You define the endpoint you're connecting to**. In Business Services, OSB will take your WSDL and call whatever endpoint you tell it to.  For a proxy service, the server OSB runs on will dictate what port address it's going to use, outside of the Endpoint URI [image: Business Service Configuration Screenshot with Endpoint URI highlighted] that *you've defined for it*.

I would read Oracle's documentation on the Concepts and Architecture for OSB.  It covers alot of this background information on implementing proxy and business services, and might point you to the more specific question you want answered.  In particular, [section 2.2 covers the Proxy and business service abstraction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e15020/architecture_overview.htm#i1094774) concept pretty well:

**[Oracle® Fusion Middleware Concepts and Architecture for Oracle Service Bus
11g Release 1 (11.1.1.7)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e15020/toc.htm)**